# How do you print to stderr in R?

Tags: r, printing, stderr

How do you print to `stderr` in `R`?

This would especially useful for scripts written in `Rscript`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Actually the following works for me:

```
write("prints to stderr", stderr())

write("prints to stdout", stdout())
```

Comment: This is on Linux, with R 2.8.1 (using Rscript)

Comment: This code also works on Windows.  For more formatting control, you can use cat instead of write.

Comment: FWIW, this is limited, in that it only works if the first argument can be outputted by `cat`. There are classes that require `print` to work, where you have to use `sink`, as Galwegian says below.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a more flexible version for debugging/verbose use in Rscript. Not only it prints to `stderr` as you ask, but it also allows you to pass variable number of arguments, types etc, like `printf` does.

```
v <- function(...) cat(sprintf(...), sep='', file=stderr())
```

Now you can do things like:

```
v("name: %s  age: %d\n", name, age)
```

etc.

Comment: This is great!!! For ones who didn't understand the ... , Refer to this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function

Answer (score 13):

```
message('for writing diagnostic info to standard error')
```

> message is used for generating ‘simple’ diagnostic messages which are neither warnings nor errors, but nevertheless represented as conditions. Unlike warnings and errors, a final newline is regarded as part of the message, and is optional. The default handler sends the message to the stderr() connection.

Comment: seems the best solution to me

Answer (score 9):

Contrary to the accepted answer's suggestion to use the [`write()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/write.html) function, this would be an inappropriate use of the function as it is designed to be used for **writing data** to a file instead of messages. From the [`write()` documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/write.html), we have:

> The data (usually a matrix) x are written to file file. If x is a two-dimensional matrix you need to transpose it to get the columns in file the same as those in the internal representation.

Moreover, note that `write()` provides a convenience wrapper for **data** output of columns.

```r
write
# function (x, file = "data", ncolumns = if (is.character(x)) 1 else 5, 
#     append = FALSE, sep = " ") 
# cat(x, file = file, sep = c(rep.int(sep, ncolumns - 1), "\n"), 
#     append = append)
```

---

That said, I would recommend using [`cat()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cat.html) alongside of the appropriate [condition handler `stderr()` or `stdout()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/showConnections.html) in `file = ...` parameter.

Thus, to write a message to standard **error**, one should use:

```r
cat("a message that goes to standard error", file = stderr())
```

Or:

```r
message("also sent to standard error")
```

For standard **out**, just use `cat()` directly as it is setup to write to `stdout()` by default.

```r
cat("displays in standard out by default")
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem with write: `stdout`, `stdin`, and `stderr` [are handled like any other file (at least in *nix systems)](https://www.howtogeek.com/435903/what-are-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-on-linux/) with their own file descriptors.

Comment: The `write()` function in _R_ is a convenience wrapper for outputting uniformly formatted data to a file. When writing text -- like status updates -- `message()` is better suited for the task as it is pre-configured to write to `stderr()`. Similarly, `cat()` excels at writing to `stdout()`.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to configure the print
>   function to print to stderr?

[From Ripley himself](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-November/060575.html):

> No, but where standard output goes is
>   controlled by sink(), so you can 
>   achieve the same effect.  R internally
>   has no idea what output comes from 
>   print() (which is not just one
>   function but hundreds of methods).