# How to use R's ellipsis feature when writing your own function?

Tags: r, function, parameters, ellipsis, variadic

The R language has a nifty feature for defining functions that can take a variable number of arguments. For example, the function `data.frame` takes any number of arguments, and each argument becomes the data for a column in the resulting data table. Example usage:

```
> data.frame(letters=c("a", "b", "c"), numbers=c(1,2,3), notes=c("do", "re", "mi"))
  letters numbers notes
1       a       1    do
2       b       2    re
3       c       3    mi
```

The function's signature includes an ellipsis, like this:

```
function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, 
    stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors()) 
{
    [FUNCTION DEFINITION HERE]
}
```

I would like to write a function that does something similar, taking multiple values and consolidating them into a single return value (as well as doing some other processing). In order to do this, I need to figure out how to "unpack" the `...` from the function's arguments within the function. I don't know how to do this. The relevant line in the function definition of `data.frame` is `object <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]`, which I can't make any sense of.

So how can I convert the ellipsis from the function's signature into, for example, a list?

To be more specific, how can I write `get_list_from_ellipsis` in the code below?

```
my_ellipsis_function(...) {
    input_list <- get_list_from_ellipsis(...)
    output_list <- lapply(X=input_list, FUN=do_something_interesting)
    return(output_list)
}

my_ellipsis_function(a=1:10,b=11:20,c=21:30)
```

---

### Edit

It seems there are two possible ways to do this. They are `as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]` and `list(...)`. However, these two do not do exactly the same thing. (For differences, see examples in the answers.) Can anyone tell me what the practical difference between them is, and which one I should use?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I read answers and comments and I see that few things weren't mentioned:

1. `data.frame` uses `list(...)` version. Fragment of the code:

   ```
   object <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
   mrn <- is.null(row.names)
   x <- list(...)
   ```

   `object` is used to do some magic with column names, but `x` is used to create final `data.frame`.
   For use of unevaluated `...` argument look at `write.csv` code where `match.call` is used.
2. As you write in comment result in Dirk answer is not a list of lists. Is a list of length 4, which elements are `language` type. First object is a `symbol` - `list`, second is expression `1:10` and so on. That explain why `[-1L]` is needed: it removes expected `symbol` from provided arguments in `...` (cause it is always a list).
   As Dirk states `substitute` returns "parse tree the unevaluated expression".
   When you call `my_ellipsis_function(a=1:10,b=11:20,c=21:30)` then `...` "creates" a list of arguments: `list(a=1:10,b=11:20,c=21:30)` and `substitute` make it a list of four elements:

   ```
   List of 4
   $  : symbol list
   $ a: language 1:10
   $ b: language 11:20
   $ c: language 21:30
   ```

   First element doesn't have a name and this is `[[1]]` in Dirk answer. I achieve this results using:

   ```
   my_ellipsis_function <- function(...) {
     input_list <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))
     str(input_list)
     NULL
   }
   my_ellipsis_function(a=1:10,b=11:20,c=21:30)
   ```
3. As above we can use `str` to check what objects are in a function.

   ```
   my_ellipsis_function <- function(...) {
       input_list <- list(...)
       output_list <- lapply(X=input_list, function(x) {str(x);summary(x)})
       return(output_list)
   }
   my_ellipsis_function(a=1:10,b=11:20,c=21:30)
    int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    int [1:10] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
    int [1:10] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
   $a
      Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00 
   $b
      Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      11.0    13.2    15.5    15.5    17.8    20.0 
   $c
      Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      21.0    23.2    25.5    25.5    27.8    30.0
   ```

   It's ok. Lets see `substitute` version:

   ```
      my_ellipsis_function <- function(...) {
          input_list <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))
          output_list <- lapply(X=input_list, function(x) {str(x);summary(x)})
          return(output_list)
      }
      my_ellipsis_function(a=1:10,b=11:20,c=21:30)
       symbol list
       language 1:10
       language 11:20
       language 21:30
      [[1]]
      Length  Class   Mode 
           1   name   name 
      $a
      Length  Class   Mode 
           3   call   call 
      $b
      Length  Class   Mode 
           3   call   call 
      $c
      Length  Class   Mode 
           3   call   call
   ```

   Isn't what we needed. You will need additional tricks to deal with these kind of objects (as in `write.csv`).

If you want use `...` then you should use it as in Shane answer, by `list(...)`.

Answer (score 41):

You can convert the ellipsis into a list with `list()`, and then perform your operations on it:

```
> test.func <- function(...) { lapply(list(...), class) }
> test.func(a="b", b=1)
$a
[1] "character"

$b
[1] "numeric"
```

So your `get_list_from_ellipsis` function is nothing more than `list`.

A valid use case for this is in cases where you want to pass in an unknown number of objects for operation (as in your example of `c()` or `data.frame()`).  It's not a good idea to use the `...` when you know each parameter in advance, however, as it adds some ambiguity and further complication to the argument string (and makes the function signature unclear to any other user).  The argument list is an important piece of documentation for function users.

Otherwise, it is also useful for cases when you want to pass through parameters to a subfunction without exposing them all in your own function arguments.  This can be noted in the function documentation.

Comment: I know about using the ellipsis as a pass-through for arguments to subfunctions, but it is also common practice among R primitives to use the ellipsis in the way I have described. In fact, both the `list` and `c` functions work in this way, but both are primitives, so I can't easily inspect their source code to understand how they work.

Comment: `rbind.data.frame` use this way.

Comment: If `list(...)` is sufficient, why do R builtins such as `data.frame` use the longer form `as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]` instead?

Comment: As I didn't create `data.frame`, I don't know the answer to that (that said, I'm sure that there *is* a good reason for it).  I use `list()` for this purpose in my own packages and have yet to encounter a problem with it.

Answer (score 39):

Just to add to Shane and Dirk's responses: it is interesting to compare

```
get_list_from_ellipsis1 <- function(...)
{
  list(...)
}
get_list_from_ellipsis1(a = 1:10, b = 2:20) # returns a list of integer vectors

$a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$b
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

with

```
get_list_from_ellipsis2 <- function(...)
{
  as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
}
get_list_from_ellipsis2(a = 1:10, b = 2:20) # returns a list of calls

$a
1:10

$b
2:20
```

As it stands, either version appears suitable for your purposes in `my_ellipsis_function`, though the first is clearly simpler.

Answer (score 20):

You gave half the answer already.  Consider

```
R> my_ellipsis_function <- function(...) {
+   input_list <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))
+ }
R> print(my_ellipsis_function(a=1:10, b=2:20))
[[1]]
list

$a
1:10

$b
11:20

R>
```

So this took two arguments `a` and `b` from the call and converted it to a list.  Wasn't that what you asked for?

Comment: Not quite what I want. That actually appears to return a list of lists. Notice the `[[1]]`. Also, I'd like to know how the magic incantation `as.list(substitute(list(...)))` works.

Comment: The inner `list(...)` creates a `list` object based on the arguments. Then `substitute()` creates the parse tree for the unevaluated expression; see the help for this function. As well as a good advanced text on R (or S). This is not trivial stuff.

Comment: Ok, what about the `[[-1L]]` part (from my question)? Shouldn't it be `[[1]]`?

Comment: You need to read up on indexing. The minus means 'exclude', i.e. `print(c(1:3)[-1])` will print 2 and 3 only. The `L` is a new-fangled way to ensure it ends up as a integer, this is done a lot in the R sources.

Comment: I don't need to read up on indexing, but I *do* need to pay closer attention to the output of the commands that you show. The difference between the `[[1]]` and the `$a` indices made me think that nested lists were involved. But now I see that what you actually get is the list I want, but with an extra element at the front. So then the `[-1L]` makes sense. Where does that extra first element come from, anyway? And is there any reason I should use this instead of simply `list(...)`?

Answer (score 7):

This works as expected.
The following is an interactive session:

```
> talk <- function(func, msg, ...){
+     func(msg, ...);
+ }
> talk(cat, c("this", "is", "a","message."), sep=":")
this:is:a:message.
>
```

Same, except with a default argument:

```
> talk <- function(func, msg=c("Hello","World!"), ...){
+     func(msg, ...);
+ }
> talk(cat,sep=":")
Hello:World!
> talk(cat,sep=",", fill=1)
Hello,
World!
>
```

As you can see, you can use this to pass 'extra' arguments to a function within your function if the defaults are not what you want in a particular case.