# R: using a list for ellipsis arguments

Tags: r, parameters, function, ellipsis

I have run into a situation where I need to take all the extra arguments passed to an R function and roll them into an object for later use. I thought the [previous question about ellipses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function) in functions would help me, but I still can't quite grasp how to do this. Here is a very simple example of what I would like to do:

```
newmean <- function(X, ...){
  args <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  return(mean(X, args))
}
```

I've tried a number of different formulations of args in the above example and tried unlisting args in the return call. But I can't make this work. Any tips?

I realize that I could do this:

```
newmean <- function(X, ...){
    return(mean(X, ...))
}
```

But I need to have the ... arguments in an object which I can serialize and read back into another machine.

Comment: I completely misunderstood your question so I delete my answer. One thing to add - use `substitute[-1L]` hack only when is needed, if you need values only then `list(...)` is sufficient, if you want pass arguments further then pass as `...`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about

```
newmean <- function(X, ...){
  args <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  z<-list(X)
  z<-c(z,args)
  do.call(mean,z)
}
```

Comment: you've been helping me a lot lately! Thanks again.

Comment: @JD, am learning stuff too in trying to answer your questions.

Comment: Why the trouble? A simple `list(...)` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: @qed That example comes from data.frame. No one seems to be able to figure out what edge case it was trying to avoid.