# Pass ... argument to another function

Tags: r

I am writing a function foo(..., lev) on the base of makeContrasts function of package limma (of bioconductor):

```
makeContrasts(..., contrasts=NULL, levels)
```

I want to pass the ... argument of foo 'as-is' to makeContrasts. Here is my code:

```
foo = function(..., lev) {
    e = substitute(list(...))
    makeContrasts(e[[2]], levels=lev)
}

foo(a + b, design)
```

The reason I have used e[[2]] is that e will be **list(a+b)** and e[[1]] is **list** but e[[2]] is what I need: **a + b**

But the problem is that the actual argument passed to makeContrast is  **e[[2]]** and not **a + b**.
So what to do?

The complete parameter assignments are as below:

```
ct = factor(c("a","b"))
design = model.matrix(~0+ct)
colnames(design)=levels(ct)
makeContrasts(a+b,levels=design) # It works
foo(a+b, design) # Does not work
```

Comment: Why do you wrap `...` in `list` in the first place?

Comment: Can you please add your code of the function substitute? If you are returning a function, add () after the name to invoke it.

Comment: @sgroh: `substitute` is a primitive in R.

Comment: I'm sorry, the valid solution is what you said in your answer :)

Comment: STILL NO WORKING EXAMPLE. Need examples of what "a", "b" , and 'design' would be if we are to work on this further. You seem to think that the expression `a+b` will be represented internally by `e[[1]] + e[[2]]`. That is just wrong. The first element of a functional expression is the function name, in this case "+", while you probably want e[[3]] which would be the second item in the argument list.

Comment: no need for `substitute` as far as I can see, all you want is `makeContrasts(..., levels = lev)`, see my answer.

Comment: It now becomes clear that you did NOT want to pass only `b`. And it should be clear why we ask for complete data and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A may be over simplifying the problem, but does the following not just work

```
foo = function(..., lev) {
 makeContrasts(...,levels =lev)
}

foo(a + b,b+c, lev =letters[1:3])


## Contrasts
## Levels a + b b + c
## a     1     0
## b     1     1
## c     0     1
```

## using your example

I don't appear to be oversimplifying.

If `...` contain the arguments to be passed to another function, then all you need is to pass `...` to that function. `...`

```
ct = factor(c("a","b"))
design = model.matrix(~0+ct)
colnames(design)=levels(ct)
makeContrasts(a+b,levels=design) 
## Contrasts
## Levels a + b
##  a     1
##  b     1
foo(a+b, lev = design)
## Contrasts
## Levels a + b
##  a     1
##  b     1
```

Comment: Thanks. Your simple answer was perfect. However I don't understand how R interprets 'a + b' while these objects does not exist, and what to do if I want to modify the ... argument and then pass it over?

Comment: I will make a new question how R interprets ... arguments

Comment: Don't --- there are questions already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414078/unpacking-argument-lists-for-ellipsis-in-r http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142731/r-using-a-list-for-ellipsis-arguments  search [r] ellipsis

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you simply need to remove the `list` call:

```
> foo <- function(...) f(substitute(...))
> f <- function(...) eval(...)
> a <- 1; b <- 3
> foo(a+b)
[1] 4
```

Comment: Thanks Jashua. The problem is that f(...) is part of a pakcage and is something like this: f(...) { e = subsitute(list(...));  . . . }. The problem is that the value of e would be list(substitute(...)) and not a + b

Comment: @AliSharifi: that's confusing. Can you update your question with a definition of `f`, some sample data, and the expected output?

Comment: @AliSharifi: please provide values for `a`, `b`, and `design`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass a + b as a string, add quotes. You could also set an object to be "a + b" and pass the object.

Comment: This is not the case. I am not trying to pass a + b as an string, but it would be an "unevaluated" statement. The true input to the f(...) is a + b and not "a + b"

Answer (score 0):

```
a=3, 
b="test"
 foo = function(...) {
    e = substitute(...)
     eval(e[[3]]) 
}

foo(a + b)

foo(a + b)
[1] "test"
```

As pointed out by others,  your expectations remain unclear. Possibly you do not want evaluation and only want the symbol:

```
foo = function(...) {
    e = substitute(...); str( e[[3]])
    return(e[[3]]) 
}

foo(a + b)
# symbol b
#b
```