# How do I get the names of the arguments passed to ... in a function?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using substitute to get argument name with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754367/using-substitute-to-get-argument-name-with)

Note that this is -different- from getting the vectors themselves with `list(...)` or something of that form. What I'd like to be able to do is simply 'echo' all arguments passed into `...`, before any parsing is done.

Eg: I want a function that might act simply like:

```
f(apple, banana, car)
## --> returns c("apple", "banana", "car"), 
## ie, skips looking for the objects apple, banana, car
```

The closest I've gotten is

```
f <- function(...) {
  return( deparse( substitute( ... ) ) )
}
```

but this only returns the first argument 'caught' by the `...`. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks - the answer provided by Marek does what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f <- 
  function(...){
     match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`  
  }
```

Some explnation from ?match.call:

```
 1. match.call returns a call in which all of the specified arguments are specified by their full names .
 2. Here it is used to pass most of the call to another function, often model.frame. 
    Here the common idiom is that expand.dots = FALSE
```

Here some tests:

```
f(2)        # call of a static argument  
[[1]]
[1] 2

> f(x=2)  # call of setted argument
$x
[1] 2

> f(x=y)  # call of symbolic argument
$x
y
```

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately - if I pass in the name of an object that doesn't exist in the environment I'll get an error saying the object isn't found. I want to be able to get the name even if the object doesn't exist.

Comment: This does the trick - looks like 'match.call()' is the magic function here. Thanks!

Comment: @CauchyDistributedRV The title of the question was a little bit confusing. I suugest you change it , to mapping of the names of arguments

Comment: `match.call(expand.dots = F)$\`...\`` would be slightly more idiomatic

Comment: @hadley `strict()` would tell you not to use `F` here ;-) (yes, I also need to clean up a shitload of old comments and posts...)