# How to pass alternative arguments through wrapper function?

Tags: r

I would like to write a wrapper function for two functions that take optional arguments.

Here is an example of a function `fun` to wrap `funA` and `funB`

```
funA <- function(x = 1, y = 1) return(x+y)
funB <- function(z = c(1, 1) return(sum(z))

fun <- function(x, y, z)
```

I would like `fun` to return `x+y` if `x` and `y` are provided, and `sum(z)` if a vector `z` is provided.

I have tried to see how the `lm` function takes such optional arguments, but it is not clear exactly how, e.g., `match.call` is being used here.

After finding related questions (e.g. [How to use R's ellipsis feature when writing your own function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057341/199217) and [using substitute to get argument name with](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5754367/199217) )), I have come up with a workable solution.

My solution has just been to use

```
fun <- function(...){
  inputs <- list(...)
  if (all(c("x", "y") %in% inputs){
    ans <- funA(x, y)
   } else if ("z" %in% inputs){
    ans <- funB(z)
   }
```

Is there a better way?

*Note:* Perhaps this question can be closed as a duplicate, but hopefully it can serve a purpose in guiding other users to a good solution: it would have been helpful to have expanded my search to variously include `ellipsis`, `substitute`, in addition to  `match.call`.

Comment: @agstudy I found a useable solution part way through, but would like to know a more robust approach.

Answer (score 4):

Use `missing`.  This returns `funA(x, y)` if both `x` and `y` are provided and returns `funB` if they are not but `z` is provided and if none of them are provided it returns `NULL`:

```
fun <- function(x, y, z) {
          if (!missing(x) && !missing(y)) {
             funA(x, y) 
          } 
          else if (!missing(z))  {
             funB(z)
          }
```

This seems to answer your question as stated but note that the default arguments in `funA` and `funB` are never used so perhaps you really wanted something different?

Note the `fun` that is provided in the question only works if the arguments are named whereas the `fun` here works even if they are provided positionally.

Comment: I don't want to use the defaults necessarily, I just put them in for illustration (e.g. that one function takes two numbers, the other a vector)

Answer (score 2):

I would something like for example this using `match.call`. This is similar to your solution but more robust.

```
fun <- function(...){
  arg <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
  f <- ifelse(length(arg)>1,"funA","funB")
  do.call(f,arg)
}

fun(x=1,y=2) ## or fun(1,2) no need to give named arguments
[1] 3
> fun(z=1:10) ## fun(1:10)
[1] 55
```