# How to create and use a formula in function in r?

Tags: r, function, formula

I am trying to create a reusable function. In the function, I would like to self-define a formula and then test the formula with the `lm` in my function and output the summary of the regression results.

I have tried using `as.formula` function to create my own formula in my self-defined function, but I get error messages with the following codes, not sure why, could anyone help me?

```r
# create the data
x <- c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,1,1,2,1)
y <- c(2,3,4,5,1,3,4,5,6,7,2)
z <- c(2,3,4,1,2,3,33,5,2,4,5)
i <- c(2,4,4,5,1,3,2,5,6,7,2)
j <- c(2,9,4,1,2,3,4,5,2,4,5)
k <- c(2,12,4,5,1,3,4,5,6,7,2)
q <- c(2,55,4,1,2,5,4,5,2,4,5)
m <- data.frame(x,y,z)

# the function
polyRegress <- function(pre1, pre2, dv, df){

  # This is the formula I want to test:
  # model <- lm(z ~ x + y + I(x^2) + I(x*y) + I(y^2), data=m)

  f <- as.formula(paste0(dv, " ~ ", pre1, " + ", pre2, " + ", "I(", pre1, "^2)", " + ", "I(", pre1, "*", pre2, ")", " + ", "I(", pre2, "^2)")

  results <- lm(f, data=df)
  summary(results)
}

# main
polyRegress(x, y, z, m)
polyRegress(i, j, k, m)
```

Also, in the outputs from the two `polyRegress` functions above, I want the names of the coefficients being `x, y, I(x^2), I(x * y), I(y^2)` and `i, j, I(i^2), I(i * j), I(j^2)`, rather than `pre1, pre2, I(pre1^2), I(pre1 * pre2), I(pre2^2)`

Comment: As all the data is in the data frame `m`, you don't need to input the x, y, z as well. You can write a formula as a single string then eg `as.formula("z ~ x + y...")`

Comment: I think I didn't show my question clearly. I have edited my question again. The original codes about are just an illustration of my question. The original dataset, `m`, I showed only contains 3 variables. But my actual dataset contains many. Let's say if I have a dataset which contains variables `x, y, z, i, k, j, d, q`...I want to write an function which can not only gives results from `polyRegress(x, y, z, m)`, but also from `polyRegress(i, k, j, m)`

Comment: I have edited my question again. Hope this would be clearer. Thanks @JonnyPhelps

Answer (score 1):

With your example i think you don't need to have **df** argument because x,y,z,i ... are vectors. 
 When you call *polyRegress(x, y, z, m)* you use x,y and z vectors not the colnames in m.
So, in the first case you can use solutions give by [using substitute to get argument name with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754367/using-substitute-to-get-argument-name-with)  to change coefficient's names.

```
# create the data
x <- c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,1,1,2,1)
y <- c(2,3,4,5,1,3,4,5,6,7,2)
z <- c(2,3,4,1,2,3,33,5,2,4,5)
i <- c(2,4,4,5,1,3,2,5,6,7,2)
j <- c(2,9,4,1,2,3,4,5,2,4,5)
k <- c(2,12,4,5,1,3,4,5,6,7,2)
q <- c(2,55,4,1,2,5,4,5,2,4,5)
m <- data.frame(x,y,z)

# the function
polyRegress <- function(pre1, pre2, dv){
  # change pre1 by "x" or "i" ...
  pre1 <- deparse(substitute(pre1))
  pre2 <- deparse(substitute(pre2))
  dv <- deparse(substitute(dv))

  f <- paste0(dv, " ~ ", pre1, " + ", pre2, " + ", "I(", pre1, "^2)", " + ", "I(", pre1, "*", pre2, ")", " + ", "I(", pre2, "^2)")

  results <- lm(f)
  # at this step results$call = lm(formula = f), let's change it !
  results$call <- call('lm', formula = formula(f))
  summary(results)
}

# main
polyRegress(x, y, z)
polyRegress(i, j, k)
```

But if you really want to call variable in your dataframe you have to change your arguments by character. Beaucause you want to use dataframe's colnames.

```
# create the data
m <- data.frame(x,y,z,i,j,k)
rm(x,y,z,i,j,k)

# the function
polyRegress <- function(pre1, pre2, dv, df){
  f <- paste0(dv, " ~ ", pre1, " + ", pre2, " + ", "I(", pre1, "^2)", " + ", "I(", pre1, "*", pre2, ")", " + ", "I(", pre2, "^2)")

  results <- lm(f, data = df)
  # at this step results$call = lm(formula = f, data = df), let's change it !
  results$call <- call('lm', formula = formula(f), data = substitute(df)) 
  summary(results)
}

# main
polyRegress("x", "y", "z", m)
polyRegress("i", "j", "k", m)
```

I hope i understand your demand.