# Usage of `...` (three-dots or dot-dot-dot) in functions

Tags: r, ellipsis

Where can I find documentation on the usage of `...` in functions? Examples would be useful.

Comment: For python users learning R, a quick answer would be that `...` is the R equivalent of python's keyword input (`def func(**kwargs)`)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The word used to describe `...` is "ellipsis."  Knowing this should make searching for information about the construct easier.  For example, the first hit on Google is another question on this site: [How to use R's ellipsis feature when writing your own function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function)

Comment: Actually the official name in R is `dots`, e.g. the help page is named `?dots` and "ellipsis" isn't even mentioned on the page

Comment: Regarding help files, `?dots` does not work for me, but `?'...'` does.

Answer (score 57):

A little example to get you started.

```
f <- function(x, ...)
{
  dots <- list(...)                   #1
  if(length(dots) == 0) return(NULL) 
  cat("The arguments in ... are\n")
  print(dots)
  f(...)                              #2
}

f(1,2,3,"a", list("monkey"))
```

The function, `f`, stores all but the first input argument in the ellipsis variable.  For accessing its contents, it is easiest to convert it to a list (1).  The main use however is for passing arguments to subfunctions, which requires no conversion (2).

Comment: Why in #2 call the same f function again?

Comment: @JiapengZhang It's an example of a recursive function. `f()` gets called repeatedly with different arguments each time. Run the code and see if you can understand what is happening.

Comment: This would be a great example to demonstrate `...length()` as well

Answer (score 20):

You should head over to "R Language Definition", section ***2.1.9 Dot-dot-dot***. It comes bundled with R installation. Run `help.start()` in an interactive session to bring HTML help up, and click on *The R Language Definition* link. You can use [PDF](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.pdf) or [HTML](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) version from the main site as well.

Anyway, `...` is used to match unspecified formal arguments of a function.

```
args(sapply)                                                                                                               
function (X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)                                                                    
NULL   

sapply(mtcars, mean, trim = .5)                                                                                            
    mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear                                              
 19.200   6.000 196.300 123.000   3.695   3.325  17.710   0.000   0.000   4.000                                              
   carb                                                                                                                      
  2.000
```

As you can see, I passed `trim = .5` though it's not specified as a formal argument of `sapply` function.

*(note that this example is trivial, you can use `sapply(mtcars, median)` to achieve the same result)*

Comment: If it's not specified, how do you know it's legal or valid?

Comment: @qed `trim` is an argument to the `mean` function.  The `...` in `sapply` are the mechanism for `trim` to be passed to `mean`.