# What does the element '...' mean in R?

Tags: r, syntax, parameters

I have searched a lot but I am unable to get what `...` means in R. I was thinking it is used to indicate default values for parameters of an R function, but I have no clue about it.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a complete explanation, more of a tip, but you can find some information on a lot of these symbols in the documentation just by quoting them e.g. `?"..."` and `?"["`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890576/usage-of-three-dots-or-dot-dot-dot-in-functions