# Convert List to Vectors in R (1st vector comprises of 1st element of each element of list, etc.) in R

Tags: r, list

I am wondering how to convert lists to vectors in R where each vector comprises of an element of an element of the list. In particular, I would like the 1st vector to comprise of the 1st element of each element of the list. I would like the 2nd vector to comprise of the 2nd element of each element of the list. More generally, I would like the nth vector to comprise of the nth element of each element of the list. Thus, n will equal the length of the longest element of the list.

For example, suppose we had:

```
mylist = list(c("a", "b"), c(character(0)), c(1, 2, 3))
```

I would like to create three vectors where

```
first_vector = c("a", NA, 1)
second_vector = c("b", NA, 2)
third_vector = c(NA, NA, 3)
```

As you can see in the above example, I may have additional complications due to missing values.

Thank you so much in advance for help!

-Vincent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also consider `stri_list2matrix` from the "stringi" package. Depending on the orientation desired:

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(mylist)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  NA   "1" 
# [2,] "b"  NA   "2" 
# [3,] NA   NA   "3" 

stri_list2matrix(mylist, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "b"  NA  
# [2,] NA   NA   NA  
# [3,] "1"  "2"  "3"
```

Comment: That's seems to be an awfully useful function there. `stringi` is almost as awesome as `data.table`

Comment: @DavidArenburg -Combine the two and you have A1 extreme awesomeness

Answer (score 5):

Usually creating endless amount of objects in your global environment is bad practice, and since all your vectors are of the same length, you could just create one matrix instead

```
indx <- max(lengths(mylist))
sapply(mylist, `length<-`, indx)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  NA   "1" 
# [2,] "b"  NA   "2" 
# [3,] NA   NA   "3"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! What does `...` do in R?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function) Or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890576/usage-of-three-dots-or-dot-dot-dot-in-functions)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I meant to ask what does the character before length<- do? It seems to be a single quotation mark?

Comment: It tells R that this is a function, rather I'm trying to insert something into an object called `length`, take look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449366/levels-what-sorcery-is-this)