# Inform MTurkR of AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am very new to MTurkR. I seek to tell MTurkR what my AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are.  I tried the code below but used my real keys instead of the fakekey1 and fakekey2 text:

```
request(operation, GETparameters = NULL,
    keypair = c(Sys.getenv("fakekey1"),  
                Sys.getenv("fakekey2")),
    browser = getOption('MTurkR.browser', FALSE),
    log.requests = getOption('MTurkR.log', TRUE),
    sandbox = getOption('MTurkR.sandbox', FALSE),
    verbose = getOption('MTurkR.verbose', TRUE),
    validation.test = getOption('MTurkR.test', FALSE),
    service = "AWSMechanicalTurkRequester",
    version = NULL)
```

I get this error:
Error in request(operation, GETparameters = NULL, keypair = c(Sys.getenv("fakekey1"),  : 
  No keypair provided.
Please set environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Comment: did you set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as environment variable ?

Comment: I would not call `request()` directly. There's no need for that. What operation are you actually trying to perform?

Comment: I am trying to follow code at https://github.com/leeper/MTurkR/wiki/Circumventing-Batch-Pricing

Comment: If I do not use request(), how do I set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to set credentials is using environment variables (as the error message indicates and as described [in the installation instructions](https://github.com/leeper/MTurkR/wiki/Installation)). Specifically, start your script by doing:

```
Sys.setenv(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "yourkey")
Sys.setenv(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "yoursecret")
library("MTurkR")
```

and then run the code on that page. `request()` will retrieve your keypair automatically from those environment variables.

If for some reason you don't want to set environment variables, you can pass the `keypair` argument through the `...` of any MTurkR function, e.g.:

```
AccountBalance(keypair = c("yourkey", "yoursecret"))
```

If you are new to R and unfamiliar with the use of the `...` argument in functions, you can see [an explanation of it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890576/usage-of-three-dots-or-dot-dot-dot-in-functions).

Finally, `request()` is a *low-level function*, so there is probably no reason to call it directly.