# Pass optional arguments to function, three dots

Tags: r, arguments, ellipsis

I'm confused how `...` works.

```
tt = function(...) {
  return(x)
}
```

Why doesn't `tt(x = 2)` return `2`?

Instead it fails with the error:

> Error in tt(x = 2) : object 'x' not found

Even though I'm passing `x` as argument ?

Comment: you are not passing `x` as argument.

Comment: `tt = function(x,levels) {
  if(missing(levels))
    return(x)
}
tt(x = 2)`

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890576/usage-of-three-dots-or-dot-dot-dot-in-functions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because everything you pass in the `...` stays in the `...`. Variables you pass that aren't explicitly captured by a parameter are not expanded into the local environment. The `...` should be used for values your current function doesn't need to interact with at all, but some later function does need to use do they can be easily passed along inside the `...`. It's meant for a scenario like

```
ss <- function(x) {
   x
}

tt <- function(...) {
  return(ss(...))
}

tt(x=2)
```

If your function needs the variable `x` to be defined, it should be a parameter

```
tt <- function(x, ...) {
  return(x)
}
```

If you really want to expand the dots into the current environment (and I strongly suggest that you do not), you can do something like

```
tt <- function(...) {
  list2env(list(...), environment())
  return(x)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you define three dots as an argument for your function and want it to work, you need to tell your function where the dots actually go. in your example you are neither defining `x` as an argument, neither `...` feature elsewhere in the body of your function. an example that actually works is:

```
tt <- function(x, ...){
       mean(x, ...)
}

x <- c(1, 2, 3, NA)
tt(x)
#[1] NA
tt(x, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2
```

here `...` is referring to *any other arguments that the function `mean` might take*. additionally you have a regular argument `x`. in the first example `tt(x)` just returns `mean(x)`, whilst in the second example `tt(x, na.rm = TRUE)`, passes the second argument `na.rm = TRUE` to `mean` so `tt` returns `mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way that the programmers of R use a lot is `list(...)` as in

```
tt <- function(...) {
    args <- list(...)    # As in this
    if("x" %in% names(args))
        return(args$x)
    else
        return("Something else.")
}

tt(x = 2)
#[1] 2

tt(y = 1, 2)
#[1] "Something else."
```

I believe that this is one of their favorite, if not *the* favorite, way of handling the dots arguments.