# How to define user function with `...` in R?

Tags: r, function, nested, arguments, user-defined-functions

In R documentation, it explains that

> The argument '...' can be used to allow one function to pass on argument settings to another.

I am not very sure how it works... In my imagination it is going to work like this:

```
Arithmetic <- function(x, ...) {
  calculate <- function(x, y = 1, operand = "add") {
    if (operand == "add") {return(x + y)}
    if (operand == "subtract") {return(x - y)}
    if (operand == "multiply") {return(x * y)}
    if (operand == "devide") {return(x / y)}
  }
  return(calculate(x, y, operand))
}
Arithmetic(x = 3, y = 4, operand = "subtract")
## [1] -1
```

while what happens is:

```
Error in calculate(x, y, operand) : object 'operand' not found
```

So exactly how `...` works for user-defined functions in R?

Comment: Related: [Usage of `…` (three-dots or dot-dot-dot) in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890576/usage-of-three-dots-or-dot-dot-dot-in-functions)

Answer (score 0):

This would be enough:

```
calculate <- function(x, y, operand = "add") {
  if (operand == "add") {return(x + y)}
  if (operand == "subtract") {return(x - y)}
  if (operand == "multiply") {return(x * y)}
  if (operand == "devide") {return(x / y)}
}
```

Output:

```
calculate(3, 4, "subtract")
[1] -1
```

This function would have as default the "add" `operand`, but you can change it to whatever you need.

Basically, if you have already defined parameters, there is no need for `...` .

If you would want to include the `...`, then you could start with something like:

```
calculate <- function(x, ...) {

  args_list <- list(...)

  if (args_list[[2]] == "add") {return(x + args_list[[1]])}
  if (args_list[[2]] == "subtract") {return(x - args_list[[1]])}
  if (args_list[[2]] == "multiply") {return(x * args_list[[1]])}
  if (args_list[[2]] == "devide") {return(x / args_list[[1]])}

}

calculate(3, 4, "subtract")
[1] -1
```

Comment: You are right in specifying the function, but the question focuses on the logic and use of the '...' argument.

Comment: @Tomas true, but in this specific function I don't see the purpose of '...'. If the question is only regarding its use, then there are already several answers elsewhere on Stack.