# Is there any way to control the output decimal places of the t-test function?

Tags: r, t-test

I'm using the built-in t-test function.

Code below:

```
t.test(
  mpg$cyl[mpg$model == "a4"],
  drill_df$Time_hr[mpg$model == "malibu"],
  alternative = "l",
  mu = 0,
  conf.level = 0.95,
)
```

Comment: `round(t.test(.....), 2)` ?

Comment: `options(digits=2)`? (imperfect, better to round)

Comment: @RonakShah can't use this. I've tried.
There's an error message showing:
Error in round(t.test(drill_df$Time_hr[drill_df$Region == "Antarctic"],  : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: When I run your code I get `Error in match.arg(alternative) :  'arg' should be one of “two.sided”, “less”, “greater”`

Comment: @RonakShah `t.test` returns a list of class `"htest`, `round` cannot be applied to it directly.

Comment: @RonakShah I've updated the code, changing alternative = "l".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. Write a function `t_test` calling `t.test` and then round the numbers in a `lapply` loop. The return value of `lapply` is a list, so class `"htest"` must be assigned manually before returning to caller.

```
t_test <- function(..., d = 2){
  tt <- t.test(...)
  tt <- lapply(tt, function(x){
    if(is.numeric(x)) round(x, d) else x
  })
  class(tt) <- "htest"
  tt
}

t_test(
  mpg$cyl[mpg$model == "a4"],
  mpg$cyl[mpg$model == "malibu"],
  alternative = "l",
  mu = 0,
  conf.level = 0.95,
)
#   Welch Two Sample t-test
#
#data:  mpg$cyl[mpg$model == "a4"] and mpg$cyl[mpg$model == "malibu"]
#t = -0.54, df = 8.63, p-value = 0.3
#alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is less than 0
#95 percent confidence interval:
# -Inf 0.83
#sample estimates:
#mean of x mean of y 
#     4.86      5.20
```

Comment: Just wondering if there is any meaning behind the use of ellipses?

Comment: @Bayman Yes, there is. The dots argument means *anything, any number or type of arguments*. Arguments after the ellipses must be named arguments. See `?dots`, these SO posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890576/usage-of-three-dots-or-dot-dot-dot-in-functions) or [this page](https://www.burns-stat.com/the-three-dots-construct-in-r/).