# assign attributes to a function on the fly

Tags: r

I am trying to use function A within function B. I want to fix the attributes of function A
dependent on the input from function B. As a simple example:

```
somfun<-function(x,atra){

   functionA(x,atra$subset)

}
```

Sorry if it is vague. But I need `atra` to operate as the arguments like `paste(x,sep='sss')` etc. but with an arbitrary number of arguments. `atra would be a named vector for example or whatever was appropriate.

example

```
atra<-list(a=1:2,b=3:4,c=5:6,1:2,sep='')

x<-'data'
somfun<-function(x,atra){

   c(atra[[1]],atra[[2]],atra[[3]],paste(x,atra[[5]]))

}
```

but i want all the names to preserve and paste to realise that `atra[[5]]` is saying `sep=''`

Comment: Use the ellipsis, `...`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3057341/269476

Comment: atra would be a list or vector of arbitrary length also its names etc would be dynamic.

Comment: It would be beneficial to give an actual concrete example of what you want to do.

Comment: Do you mean `atra` rather than `atr` in the second to last line in that example?

Comment: And atra[4] *isn't* `sep=''`, it's `b2="4"` (try it: `c(a=1:2,b=3:4,c=5:6,1:2,sep='')[4]`). The `sep` argument is `atra[9]`.

Comment: Did you want to make it a list rather than a vector?

Comment: @DavidRobinson yes i think list is what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `do.call` function, which can call a function using a list (including named arguments). For example:

```
do.call(paste, list("hello", "world", sep="/"))
# [1] "hello/world"
```

Comment: yes thats it `aa<-list(a=1:2,b=3,collapse=',')` `do.call(paste,aa)` for example. thanks alot