# Getting names from ... (dots)

Tags: r

In improving an `rbind` method, I'd like to extract the names of the objects passed to it so that I might generate unique IDs from those.

I've tried `all.names(match.call())` but that just gives me:

```
[1] "rbind"         "deparse.level" "..1"           "..2"
```

Generic example:

```
rbind.test <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  all.names(match.call())
}

t1 <- t2 <- ""
class(t1) <- class(t2) <- "test"
> rbind(t1,t2)
[1] "rbind"         "deparse.level" "..1"           "..2"
```

Whereas I'd like to be able to retrieve `c("t1","t2")`.

I'm aware that in general one cannot retrieve the names of objects passed to functions, but it seems like with ... it might be possible, as `substitute(...)` returns `t1` in the above example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use R's ellipsis feature when writing your own function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function)

Comment: There are some great answers on the other question. Incidentally, the term for those dots is "ellipsis" (which makes it much easier to Google).

Comment: @DavidRobinson: none of those answers apply because `rbind` and `cbind` use non-standard method dispatch.  The answer to this question is actually in the comments of one of the answers to the question you linked to.

Comment: That's a great question and in fact contained the answer but definitely not a duplicate Q.  @mnel just posted the answer right as I found it in there.  Thanks for the pointer to that (awesome!) question.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, do you want the same output as the `allnams(match.call())` but with `'..1', '..2'` replaced with `'t1','t2'`, or is `'t1','t2'` sufficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the guidance here [How to use R's ellipsis feature when writing your own function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function)

eg `substitute(list(...))`

and combining with with `as.character`

```
rbind.test <- function(...) {
  .x <-  as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
  as.character(.x)
 }
```

you can also use

```
rbind.test <- function(...){as.character(match.call(expand.dots = F)$...)}
```

Answer (score 13):

I picked this one up from [Bill Dunlap on the R Help List Serve](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-October/361774.html):

```
rbind.test <- function(...) {
    sapply(substitute(...()), as.character)
}
```

I think this gives you what you want.

Comment: Cool.  Can you explain the `...()` piece?  It's clearly not legit on its own, and I can't imagine what it would be doing inside `substitute`.

Comment: Uh no I can't Bill Dunlap is a genius I am not.  I have no clue why it works but it's his preferred method and he explains the efficiency in a post online.  Sorry I don't have the reference for it but it was within the last 4-5 months.

Comment: Well if you're confused I think it merits a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523548/confused-by).  I'm looking forward to having my mind blown.