# Confused by ...()?

Tags: r

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12417320/636656), `sapply(substitute(...()), as.character)` was used inside a function to obtain the names passed to the function.  The `as.character` part sounds fine, but what on earth does `...()` do?

It's not valid code outside of `substitute`:

```
> test <- function(...) ...()
> test(T,F)
Error in test(T, F) : could not find function "..."
```

Some more test cases:

```
> test <- function(...) substitute(...())
> test(T,F)
[[1]]
T

[[2]]
F

> test <- function(...) substitute(...)
> test(T,F)
T
```

Comment: Not sure it answers the question, but Here is an [R help link](https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-July/319252.html) in which Bill Dunlap is using this to create a function from the `...` element. Hence `...()` creates a function for each element of `...`

Comment: Yeah that's where I picked it up but that doesn't really get at how it works I don't think.

Comment: `list(...)` will evaluate the elements of `...`, while `substitute(...())` will return them unevaluated. But for the life of me I can't work out why. (I'm lost trying to find where this is in the source code)

Comment: Among many other things, I'm curious why `substitute(...)` only returns the first element of the of `...`. (Note that `test <- function(...) substitute({...}); test(T, F)` will return them both, in a fashion.

Comment: @mnel, if you're better in c than I am (not a difficult achievement), have a look in the file coerce.c in */src/main for the functions `substitute`, `substituteList` and `do_substitute`. They do deal with ellipses in a special way.

Comment: @mnel I don't think `...()` creates a function for element of `...`. `...` is a pairlist and the first argument of `substitute()` is supposed to be an expression. In an expression `(` can be used to simply group things. As all `substitute` is doing is returning the parse tree for `...`, I wonder if the `()` is just a trick of the parser or similar to get it to group the `...` somehow. As Bill's email shows, there isn't any function creation as that would show up in the resulting parse tree would it not?

Comment: My strong recommendation is not to use this construct.  ever.  Bill D. may have discovered a great sneaky trick, but given that it's pretty  much undocumented there's really no guarantee it will work in all cases or that some future mod to the core of R won't break it.  Sometimes we can be too clever for our own good :-( .  I'll retract this comment if Patrick "Inferno" Burns can show otherwise. :-)

Comment: That goes for `substitute(...[])`, too...

Comment: @mplourde `test <- function(...) substitute(...[])`
`test(T,F)`
`T[F, ]`
My mind just exploded.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman `Rgames> foo<-test(3,"four",5)
Rgames> typeof(foo)
[1] "language"
Rgames> foo
3["four", 5, ]`   So there :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a sketch of why `...()` works the way it does. I'll fill in with more details and references later, but this touches on the key points.

1. Before performing substitution on any of its components, `substitute()` first parses an R statement.
2. `...()` parses to a call object, whereas `...` parses to a name object.
3. `...` is a special object, intended only to be used in function calls. As a consequence, the C code that implements substitution takes special measures to handle `...` when it is found in a call object. Similar precautions are *not* taken when `...` occurs as a symbol. (The relevant code is in the functions `do_substitute`, `substitute`, and `substituteList` (especially the latter two) in `R_SRCDIR/src/main/coerce.c`.)

So, the role of the `()` in `...()` is to cause the statement to be parsed as a call (aka language) object, so that substitution will return the fully expanded value of the dots. It may seem surprising that `...` gets substituted for even when it's on the outside of the `()`, but: (a) calls are stored internally as list-like objects and (b) the relevant C code seems to make no distinction between the first element of that list and the subsequent ones.

---

Just a side note: for examining behavior of `substitute` or the classes of various objects, I find it useful to set up a little sandbox, like this:

```
f <- function(...) browser()
f(a = 4, 77, B = "char")
## Then play around within the browser
class(quote(...))  ## quote() parses without substituting
class(quote(...()))
substitute({...})
substitute(...(..., X, ...))
substitute(2 <- (makes * list(no - sense))(...))
```

Comment: The one bit I still don't understand is how the substitution for `...` in `substitute(...())` changes the class of the returned object. All other substitutions within call objects that I've examined (e.g. `substitute(j())`, `substitute(j(...))`, or even `j <- pairlist(x=4, y=5); substitute(j())`) return call objects. I think the answer is down at the C level of calls to `CDR`, `CAR`, `SETCDR` and `CONS`, which I'm just not able to fully follow/game out.

Comment: Continuing on this weird path, try this: `substitute((...))` and then this: `as.list(substitute((...)))`. It seems that the result in both cases is an "improper" `call` object to the function `'('`, since this function only accepts one argument. In the first case, `print` assumes it's a proper call, and shows only the first argument. In the second case, we can see all the elements of the call.