# R non-standard evaluation - passing a list

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

How can I pass a character vector using NSE:

```
fun <- function(x){
  x_  <-deparse(substitute(x))
  print(x_)
}

fun_ <- function(x){
 do_something(x)
}
```

For example,

```
fun(x= a, b, c)
```

should print interpret the argument to `x` as a vector c(a, b, c) and pass a character vector to `fun_(x)`:

```
fun_(x=c("a", "b", "c"))
```

There are additional parameters as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use commas *within* a parameter; commas separate parameters. Calling `fun(x=a,b,c)` would call `fun()` with three parameters, the first one named and the second two unnamed. If you just want to ignore the name `x=`, you can turn unquoted names to strings with

```
fun <- function(...){
  x <- sapply(substitute(...()), deparse)
  fun_(x)
}

fun_ <- function(x) {
    print(x)
}

fun(a,b,c)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" 

fun_(c("a","b","c"))
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: The `...()` command is seriously mind-bending. If you want help to digest it check out this question: [Confused by ...()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523548/confused-by)