# Passing a quoted function argument to a three-dots argument inside another function using base R

Tags: r, substitution, quote, nse, three-dots

I would like to pass quoted variables in the `group` argument of `geom_col_wrap` to the `split_group` function.

```
# I deleted the rest of the function for readability
geom_col_wrap = function(data, mapping, group, ...) {

  data |>
    split_group(group) 
}
```

```
# This function was based on the `tidytable` package
split_group = function(data, ...) {
  by_quote = as.list(substitute(...()))
  by = sapply(by_quote, deparse)

  split = vctrs::vec_split(data, data[c(by)])
  out = split[["val"]]
  names = do.call(paste, c(split[["key"]], sep = "_"))
  names(out) = names

  return(out)
}
```

`split_group` use `substitute` to quote variables, here is the problem. How can I make `split_group` recognize quote variables from `group` argument? I know it is easy to solve using `rlang`, but I need a R base solution.

```
split_group(mtcars, vs, am)
$`0_1`
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
...

$`1_1`
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
...

$`1_0`
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
...

$`0_0`
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
...
```

```
geom_col_wrap(
  mtcars,
  mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = cyl, y = hp, color = am),
  group = c(vs, am)
)

Error in `[.data.frame`(data, c(by)) : undefined columns selected
```

This error comes from `as.list(substitute(...()))`. It does not unquoted the `group` argument. Why?

Note: I cannot use dots arg to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the miraculous `...()` chain, explanation is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12545395/6574038).

```
split_group <- \(x, ...)  split(x, x[, sapply(substitute(...()), as.character)])

split_group(mtcars, vs, am)
# $`0.0`
# mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4
# Merc 450SE        16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.07 17.40  0  0    3    3
# ...
# 
# $`1.0`
# mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# ...
# 
# $`0.1`
# mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Porsche 914-2  26   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# ...
# 
# $`1.1`
# mpg cyl  disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710  22.8   4 108.0 93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Fiat 128    32.4   4  78.7 66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7 52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need the base R version of rlang's `{{ group }}` or `!!enquo(group)` workflow. Which would be using `substitute()` to grab your `group` argument, and then using `.(group)` inside `bquote()`.

However `bquote()` helps you *build* the expression, we then need to use `eval()` to evaluate your new expression.

Another thing - you're using `deparse()` in `split_group()` which would convert `c(vs, am)` to `"c(vs, am)"`. Instead we'll need to mimic tidyselect so you can use `c()` style selection (that also still works without `c()` for a single column).

Put together it looks like this.

```r
split_group = function(data, ...) {
  by_quote = as.list(substitute(...()))
  
  # Mimic tidyselect
  cols = as.list(seq_along(data))
  names(cols) = names(data)
  by = unlist(lapply(by_quote, eval, cols))

  split = vctrs::vec_split(data, data[c(by)])
  out = split[["val"]]
  names = do.call(paste, c(split[["key"]], sep = "_"))
  names(out) = names

  return(out)
}

geom_col_wrap = function(data, mapping, group, ...) {
  # Use substitute/bquote to "unquote" group arg inside split_group function
  # Much like using `{{ group }}` or `!!enquo(group)` in rlang
  group = substitute(group)
  eval(bquote(
    data |>
      split_group(.(group))
  ))
}

geom_col_wrap(
  mtcars,
  mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = cyl, y = hp, color = am),
  group = c(vs, am)
)
#> $`0_1`
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> Maserati Bora  15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> 
#> $`1_1`
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> 
#> $`1_0`
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 280       19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 280C      17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> 
#> $`0_0`
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
```

Any reason you can't use `rlang`? `vctrs` depends on `rlang` so you're already sort of using it anyway.