# How to expand an ellipsis (...) argument without evaluating it in R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, ellipsis

I need a function that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments and stores them in a variable as an expression without evaluating them. I managed to do it with `match.call` but it seems a little "kludgy".

```
foo <- function(...) {
  expr <- match.call()
  expr[[1]] <- expression
  expr <- eval(expr)
  # do some stuff with expr
  return(expr)
}

> bla
Error: object 'bla' not found
> foo(x=bla, y=2)
expression(x = bla, y = 2)
```

## Clarification

To clarify, I'm asking how to write a function that behaves like `expression()`. I can't use `expression()` directly for reasons that are too long to explain.

Comment: Look at these two questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416880/getting-names-from-dots and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function  Also look at the results for a search on [r] ellipsis

Comment: Right now it seems `foo <- expression` would just do it, no? What do you mean by "`# do some stuff with expr`"?

Comment: Just posted my answer and realised your comment is a far simpler approach

Comment: @flodel nice one... it's a bit complicated to explain here ... in reality `foo` returns another function that uses the variable `expr` defined in `foo`. to put it another way `expr` is a free variable in the anonymous function returned by `foo`. so, it's not just like `expression` :)

Comment: Have a look at the function `.` in `plyr` it may do what you want or at least point you in the right direction

Comment: @mnel the `.` function does `as.list(match.call()[-1])` which returns an unevaluated list, then an expression can be created with `as.expression`. thanks.

Comment: It's unlikely that you actually need an expression object - a list of calls is usually adequate.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The most idiomatic way is:

```
f <- function(x, y, ...) {
  match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`
}
```

Comment: +1 Idiomatic indeed - and it is used widely in base R, e.g. in the code for linear models specified via a formula in `lm()`.

Answer (score 5):

Using `.` from `plyr` as a prototype

```
foo <-   function (...) 
  {
  as.expression(as.list(match.call()[-1]))
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The ultimate intended outcome is slightly vague (could you clarify a bit?). However, this may be helpful:

```
foo2 <- function(...) {
  expr <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  class(expr) <- "expression"
  expr
}
```

example:

```
foo2(x=bla, y=2)
# expression(x = bla, y = 2)
```

Comment: glad to help.  If it suits, please feel free to give it the tick mark

Comment: i give you the tick although i'm probably going to use @mnel's solution because is a little bit cleaner

Comment: @ErnestA Well then you should have put the tick on the other answer! :)    It's still unclear how specifically you are using this.  If you will use `match.call()` take a look at the documentation for `expand.dots`, as you might need to set that to `FALSE`.