# function to load multiple packages with input as non-character list

Tags: r, ellipsis, expression-evaluation

I got tired of starting my scripts with `require(data.table); require(ggplot2)` etc etc.  I know that I could do something like `lapply(c('data.table', 'ggplot2'), require, character.only=T)`, but it would just return a warning (not an error) for a missing package, plus I wanted my own function `require_mult(...)` to keep my scripts cleaner.  So I wrote the function:

```
require_mult <- function(...){
  arg_list <- list(...)
  if(any(!sapply(arg_list, is.character)) ) stop('require_mult must have character arguments')
    check <- tryCatch({pkg_array <- unlist(arg_list)
                       loaded <- sapply(pkg_array, require, character.only=TRUE, quietly=TRUE)
                       message('Loaded packages: ',
                               paste(pkg_array, collapse=', ') ) },
                       warning = function(w) stop(w), # I want execution to halt if a package is missing
                       error = function(e) stop(e)
                       )
}
```

Which seems to work as desired (e.g., loads for `require_mult('data.table','ggplot2')`, errors for `require_mult('data.table','ggplotfoo')`), but I would like to make this `require_mult(...)` work for `character.only=FALSE`.  I looked at the definition of `require`, which uses

```
if (!character.only) 
        package <- as.character(substitute(package))
```

But I can't figure out how to apply `substitute` across an unevaluated expression that's really a comma-delimited list.

I know this application is pretty pointless and academic, but it would enrich my understanding of R expression evaluation if there is in fact a way to write a `require_mult` that could be used for `require_mult(data.table, ggplot2)` etc.

An explanation of why this can't be done would also be acceptable.

Comment: You don't want to use `require` here - you might find this article by Yihui Xie useful: http://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/

Comment: @TARehman I get that -- but can you figure out how to pass multiple package names to `library`?  This doesn't work:  `lapply(c('data.table','ggplot2'), library, character.only=T)`  If you can provide a solution with `library` by all means please do so.

Comment: I believe that you just want `do.call`. Do you specifically need the list of packages being passed to be non-character? I could see writing a wrapper function for that. Or is it that it needs to raise an _error_, not a _warning_?

Comment: @TARehman good point with `do.call`, but yes I'm specifically interested in whether it is possible to pass a non-character list of packages.  Maybe I'll edit the title of the question accordingly.  Also, I think that my change to how `require` responds to not-loaded packages (via `tryCatch`) might mitigate the pitfalls in that article, but that's a side issue.

Comment: This is actually interesting. I'll see if I can devise a way to do this.

Comment: @TARehman thanks for your interest.  Re: `do.call`, try `do.call(what= library, args = list("ggplot2", "thisisnotapackage"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98358/discussion-between-tarehman-and-c8h10n4o2).

Comment: I think you may want to look at the *lack an* package's `p_load` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned something here today! You can use `match.call` to obtain the arguments passed in `...` without evaluating them. (Presumably, you could do this with named arguments...? I need to experiment more on that.) I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353847/how-to-expand-an-ellipsis-argument-without-evaluating-it-in-r) to build the very simple function below. As you can see, it breaks when reaching the package that does not exist.

I think you could use this to build further.

```
library_mult <- function(...) {
    args <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`
    for(x in args) {

        x <- as.character(substitute(x))
        library(x,character.only = TRUE)
    }
}

> library_mult(MASS,thisisnopack)

Error in library(x, character.only = TRUE) : 
  there is no package called ‘thisisnopack’
```

Comment: This is awesome.  I really think you should post it to [R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) for inclusion in a future version of base R, because the default way of loading multiple libraries is tedious.  Thanks!