# How R interprets ... arguments?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use R's ellipsis feature when writing your own function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function)

I am wondering how R interprets ... arguments?

For instance consider the `makeContrasts(..., contrasts=NULL, levels)` of package `limma`. You can run:

```
 > require(limma)
 > makeContrasts(a + b, b+c, levels=letters[1:3])

       Contrasts
 Levels a + b b + c
      a     1     0
      b     1     1
      c     0     1
```

and it interprets the parameters `a + b, b+c` without `a, b` and `c` being already defined as R objects.

I tried to make a similar function:

```
foo = function(...) {
    print(typeof(...))
}

> foo(a + b) 
Error in typeof(...) : object 'a' not found
```

So I am really confused what type of object is really passed to `makeContrasts`? And is there anyway to modify this object?

Comment: Search for `[r] ellipsis` on SO and you will find many questions from which you will be able to find your answers. Also the [r-intro](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#The-three-dots-argument) and other docs have all this information\

Comment: Also, if you want your function to process arguments like `limma::makeContrasts`, type `limma::makeContrasts` to have a look 'inside' it.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already done your recommended ideas. My question of what is the type of `a + b` was not answered anywhere.

Comment: IF you read the R manuals it is clear Try [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html). (perhaps the first link did not have everything you were looking for, the `R-Lang` is detailed and easy to read

Comment: That's hard to answer because `a + b` is many things. It is (at least): (1) a supplied (but unmatched) argument to the function call `makeContrasts(a+b)`; (2) the expression slot of one of the promise objects stored in the `...` special object; (3) a "call" or "language" object, such as is returned by typing `quote(a + b)`

Comment: Thanks Josh. Better to post it as an answer such that I can mark this question answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a "language expression". When you pass it to `typeof` the interpreter attempts to find a name to match to `a` and fails, so it generates an error. If you processed it with functions that handle items of type "language" you get a (more) sensible result.

As it is take a look at this:

```
> a="aa"
> typeof(a+b)
Error in typeof(a + b) : object 'b' not found
> b="bb"
> typeof(a+b)
Error in a + b : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

We fixed the non-existence of `a` and then the R interpreter wanted to be able to find `b` and then it realized that `+` was not being given numeric arguments. So the interpreter was attempting to evaluate the expression `a+b` in it usual fashion and reporting problems as it encountered them. In my response to your at that time incomplete question about mimicking `makeContrasts` I offered a mechanism for seeing what the R interpreter was doing with that expression:

```
 foo = function(...) {
      e <- substitute(...)
      e[[1]]
 }

  foo(a + b)
# `+`
```

When you want to examine the nature of something that is not a named element in the workspace with `typeof` which is otherwise expecting to get a character value,  you need to `quote` it:

```
> typeof(quote(a+b))
[1] "language"
> typeof(quote("a"))
[1] "character"
```