# R function Parameters

Tags: r

As my project is getting bigger and bigger, I am finding it hard to keep track of all the parameters. Are there any efficient ways in R, whereby aggregate parameters in structures?

For example, in one of my programs, if

```
take.bus = TRUE
```

Then the following parameters will be used.

```
bus.number
bus.route
bus.stop
```

As my programs is really big, there are several of these examples whereby parameter usage are dependent on one single variable. I was thinking if its possible to avoid displaying the dependent parameters (ie bus.number) when take.bus is FALSE.

I am not sure if this question fits here. Comment if its off topic.

EDIT:

To be more precise: consider the following function:

```
function(take.bus,bus.number, bus.route, bus.stop){

  if(take.bus == T){
    x<-temp.func(bus.number,bus.route,bus.stop)
   }
}
```

So none of the secondary parameters "bus.number, bus.route, bus.stop", will be used if "take.bus == F"

Comment: I think the question is fine, but I think some more details wouldn't hurt. For example, what do you mean by "... then the following parameters will be used"? If `take.bus` evaluates to TRUE, you assign value to those parameters, and if not, they get a NULL value or don't get used at all?

Comment: my parameter input has more than 20 parameters, but most of them are like the above example, where whether they will be used will be entirely based on if one parameter is "switched on or off".

Comment: @user1234440 if those three variables aren't used in a particular function call, you don't have to supply them, that is, `f(FALSE)` would not raise an error.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I thought you had to supply everything that are used. I am currently implementing parameters groupings so that it is less cluttered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If those three arguments aren't used in a particular function call, you don't have to supply them, that is, `f(FALSE)` would not raise an error.

This a feature of how R handles argument passing, which is a little different than other popular languages. For a particular function call, R won't evaluate arguments (missing or not) supplied unless the arguments in question are actually required to execute the function.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew's answer works in some cases, but you'll find that if you use arguments even inside a block you will get an error if they aren't supplied and don't have a default. So:

```
many <- function(one, two, three) {print (one);}
many("bob")
> "bob"
```

Works fine, but

```
more <- function(one, two, three) {
  print (one) 
  if(!is.null(two)) { 
    print(two)
  }
}
more("bob")
> [1] "bob"
> Error in is.null(two) : 'two' is missing
```

Is problematic. You can assign default values of null to the arguments but then you will want to actually pass in parameters. You can use an [ellipsis](http://rfunction.com/archives/73) to pass in an arbitrary number of parameters (and you can optionally name them). Bounds checking the ellipsis is a bit tricky. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function) for some more info.

Also.

**Don't use "T" and "F"!**

I can assign `T <- FALSE` and `F <- TRUE`, as they aren't reserved words.