# What Does (...) mean in R?

Tags: r

I'm sure this is a silly question, but I just came across some code in R and it involves this line:

```
query <- function(...) dbGetQuery(mychannel, ...)
```

In context from the blog I saw it on:
http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/2011/12/query-mysql-database-from-r-using.html

So what is the (...) in regards to function doing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function  *"a nifty feature for defining functions that can take a variable number of arguments."*

Comment: Note that you can get documentation for functions that don't look like functions using quotation marks: `?"..."`, `?"["`, ?`==` all work.