# R: Calculate standard deviation in cols in a data.frame despite of NA-Values

Tags: r

Good Morning,
I got a lot of data and i have to calculate with it. There are 25 columns (variables) and each column contains thousands of values. But also missing values.
I calculated the mean with

```
colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

How can i calculate the sd of each column and ignore the NA-values?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794284/means-and-sd-for-columns-in-a-dataframe-with-na-values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try,

```
apply(df, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

As the output of `apply` is a matrix, and you will most likely have to transpose it, a more direct and safer option is to use `lapply` or `sapply` as noted by @docendodiscimus,

```
sapply(df, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Ernsthaft, 2 means that we are iterating on every column of the data frame. If we put 1, then we are iterating over rows and 1:2 over each individual value

Comment: ok that was new and interesting for me. Thank you for helping a beginner :)

Comment: Take care when usng `apply` on a `data.frame` since it converts it to matrix which in turn may result in unexpected type coercion. To iterate over data.frame columns, it's usually safer to use `lapply` or `sapply`, i.e. `sapply(df, sd, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: what sort of type coercion could one realistically expect? One does not normally calculate the standard deviation of characters/factors?

Answer (score 3):

If we convert to `matrix`, `colSds` from `matrixStats` can be used

```
library(matrixStats)
colSds(as.matrix(df), na.rm=TRUE)
```

---

Or we can use `summarise_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sd(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the functioin `summarise_each()` has been deprecated, here is an up-to-date example using `dplyr`:

```
df1 %>% summarise_all(funs(sd(., na.rm = FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

> sd(variablenname,na.rm=TRUE)

This works for me. Replace "variablename" with the variable you use.