# Writing R function with uncertain numbers of variables, using for table()

Tags: r, function

I'm not quite familiar with R function dealing with variables used.
Here's the problem:

I want to built a function, of which variables `...` are column names of data frame used for `table()`.

```
f <- function (data, ...){
    T <- with(data, table(...)  # ... variables input
    return(T)
}
```

How can I deal with the code?
Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: `f <- function(data, vectorofcolumnnames) table(data[, vectorofcolumnnames])`

Comment: Thanks for help!
I'm just curious about how `...` works as a list in the function.
And in what circumstances I should use `...` ?

Comment: Have you studied section 10.4 of An Introduction to R?

Comment: Yes. But I still can't figure it out why arguments can't be used like this?
`f <- function (data, ...){
  T <- with(data,
       table(...))
  return(T)
}
`
Thank you for the patience in answering a beginners question

Comment: Worth reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often far easier to avoid non-standard evaluation and use character strings to reference the columns within a data.frame.

```
set.seed(1)
data1 <- data.frame(a = sample(5,5), b = sample(5,5))

f <- function (data, ...) {
    do.call(table,data[unlist(list(...))])

}
# the following calls to `f` return the same results
f(data = data1, 'a','b')
f(data = data1, c('a','b'))
a <- c('a','b')
f(data = data1, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation doesn't quite work right with `with()` apparently. Here's an alternative that should work (using sample data from @DavidArenburg)

```
set.seed(1)
data1 <- data.frame(a = sample(5,5), b = sample(5,5))

f <- function (data, ...) {
    xx <- lapply(substitute(...()), eval, data, parent.frame())
    T <- do.call(table, xx)
    return(T)
}

f(data = data1, a,b)
```