# Multiple apply arguments with sum of function value

Tags: r, sum, apply

I have a very large dataframe...

```
v.l.df <- data.frame(seq(0, 10, 0.0001),seq(0, 10, 0.0001),seq(0, 10, 0.0001))
```

...and a function with some if statements and calculations...

```
a.f <- function(cell_value,action){
  if(action == 1){
    cell_value * 1
  }

  else if(action == 2){
    cell_value * 5
  }
}
```

I now want to apply this function to the first two columns of my `v.l.df` row by row and build the sums of the returns. The new columns should thus contain (pseudo code):

```
new_col_1                                    new_col_2
a.f(v.l.df[1,1],1) + a.f(v.l.df[1,2],1)      a.f(v.l.df[1,1],2) + a.f(v.l.df[1,2],2)
a.f(v.l.df[2,1],1) + a.f(v.l.df[2,2],1)      a.f(v.l.df[2,1],2) + a.f(v.l.df[2,2],2)
...
```

How can this be achieved? I am struggeling with the multiple arguments when using apply and the sum of the returned values form the function.

EDIT: Changed the example function. Should now return the folowing

```
> a.f(2,1)
[1] 2
> a.f(2,2)
[1] 10
```

Comment: What does your function do? As it is coded, it doesn't return anything. Try to run `cell.test = 0.7` , `action = 1` and `a.f(cell.test)` should it return 100 or 70?

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the function in a wrong way. I have changed the function `a.f` in the example and it should work now.

Comment: is the first element of new_col_2 meant to be `a.f(v.l.df[1,1],2) + a.f(v.l.df[1,2],2)` ?

Comment: yes! I corrected the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in a couple of steps. You can reduce to fewer steps, but I prefer to keep it more readable:

First, apply `a.f` to all cells two times, using `action=1` and `action=2` to the first two columns of `v.1.df` (to pass aditional arguments inside `apply`, just put them after defining `FUN`):

```
action.1 = apply(v.1.df[,1:2], c(1,2), FUN = a.f, action=1)

action.2 = apply(v.1.df[,1:2] ,c(1,2), FUN = a.f, action=2)
```

Then ppply `rowSums` to both `action.1` and `action.2` and store the results in the same `data.frame`:

```
v.l.df$new.1 = rowSums(action.1)         #or v.l.df$new.1 = apply(action.1,1,sum)
v.l.df$new.2 = rowSums(action.2)         #or v.l.df$new.1 = apply(action.2,1,sum)
```

Comment: I get this error when executing action.1:
`Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> traceback()
1: apply(v.l.df[, 1:2], c(1, 2), FUN = a.f, action = 1)`

Comment: Apparently the `MARGIN` argument is missing. A `2`should do the trick.

Comment: The `c(1,2)`is the `margin` argument, it just wasn't explicit, nevertheless, I didn't have the same error with my code using your example data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your result is achieved by:

```
v.l.df$new_col_1 <- a.f(v.l.df$V1, 1) + a.f(v.l.df$V2, 1)
v.l.df$new_col_2 <- a.f(v.l.df$V1, 2) + a.f(v.l.df$V2, 2)
```

Assuming your first two columns are named `V1` and `V2` respectively.

You may also define another function

```
a.f.2 <- function(val1, val2, method) {
    a.f(val1, method) + a.f(val2, method)
}
```

And apply it as follows

```
v.l.df$new_col_1 <- a.f.2(v.l.df$V1, v.l.df$V2, 1)
v.l.df$new_col_2 <- a.f.2(v.l.df$V1, v.l.df$V2, 2)
```

You can write this summary function with `...` argument, to  take an arbitrary number of inputs.  The example below expects (and does not check for) columns of a data frame

```
a.f.n<- function(method,...){
    rowSums(sapply(...,a.f,method))
}
```

Then apply this as follows:

```
v.l.df$new_col_1 <- a.f.n(v.l.df[,1:1000], method=1)
v.l.df$new_col_2 <- a.f.n(v.l.df[,1:1000], method=2)
```

I am not sure how efficient this will be, but it is compact.  :-)

Comment: The thing is that I only posted an example. The real `v.l.df` has about 10,000 columns (instead of three) and I want to use this action for the fist 1000 or so instead of the first two. How can your answer be adapted to that fact?

Comment: One approach, as mentioned, is to build the second function to accept an arbitrary number of functions. This is a bit beyond my knowledge at this point.  I'm looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function.