# R-how to define a function with indefinite number of arguments in R

Tags: r

I'd like to create a function to accept indefinite number of arguments.
Is there a way to define a function in R?

Thanks.

Comment: we will need to know why you need a such a function and what it is supposed to return to give a sensible answer.

Comment: Probably  a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function), not sure though

Answer (score 2):

you can use the dots like this for example

```
f <- function(...) {
    arguments <- list(...)
    print(arguments)
}

f(a=1, b=2)
## $a
## [1] 1

## $b
## [1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply;). Is the number of dot must 3?