# How to provide dynamic number of arguments to a function inside a function in R?

Tags: r, function, variables, dynamic, arguments

I have a function `f1` which perform some task. Let us say, it performs the following task:

```
f1 = function(a=1,b=1,c=2){
  res = (a+b)*c
  return(res)
}
```

Now, this function is called through another function, `f2`. This function can take the dynamic number of arguments, create all possible combinations and feed the values to function `f1` as follows:

```
f2 = function(...){
  arglist = list(...)
  df = expand.grid(arglist) # Create all possible combinations of the given argument list.
  out = apply(df,1,function(x) f1(x))
  res = unlist(out)
  return(res)
}
```

Now, a user can provide value for any number of arguments of `f1` in `f2` like:

```
f2(a=10)
# Output: 22
```

However, if I try any other scenario I do not get desirable results:

```
f2(c=10)
# f2 Output: 22
# Target Output: 20

f2(a=5, c=c(5,10))
# f2 Output: 
12 12
12 22
# Target Output: 30 60
```

Any suggestions on how to pass such dynamic arguments to `f1` through `f2`?. I have looked at other questions like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649038/r-how-to-define-a-function-with-indefinite-number-of-arguments-in-r) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function) but I do not think that they address this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the change the `apply` to `do.call`, it would work as expected.  Note that `apply` with `MARGIN = 2`, loop over the columns of 'df' individually, whereas the 'f1' needs the values of all those available columns (or else use the default values) to calculate the (`(a + b) * c`)

```
f2 <- function(...){
  arglist = list(...)
  df = expand.grid(arglist) 
  do.call(f1, df)
}
```

and the `f1`

```
f1 <- function(a=1,b=1,c=2){
  (a+b)*c
 
}
```

-testing

```
> f2(a = 10)
[1] 22
> f2(c = 10)
[1] 20
> f2(a = 5, c= c(5, 10))
[1] 30 60
```