# R function handling a vector

Tags: r, function

I have a function that takes one argument and prints a string:

```
test <- function(year){
  print(paste('and year in (', year,')'))
}
```

I input a vector with one element year(2012) it will print this:

```
"and year in ( 2012 )"
```

How do I write the function so if I put test(c(2012,2013,2014))it prints this?

```
"and year in ( 2012,2013,2014 )"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using [ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function) for the task, and wrap it up within `toString`, as it can accept an unlimited amount of values and operate on all of them at once.

```
test <- function(...){
  print(paste('and year in (', toString(c(...)),')'))
}

test(2012:2014)
## [1] "and year in ( 2012, 2013, 2014 )"
```

The advantage of this approach is that it will also work for an input such as

```
test(2012, 2013, 2014)
## [1] "and year in ( 2012, 2013, 2014 )"
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>I believe this answer is simpler than the one by [David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923632/r-function-handling-a-vector/31923721#31923721).</strike> Here's a slightly different solution than the one by [David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923632/r-function-handling-a-vector/31923721#31923721). You could include another paste in the function using the `collapse` option. For example:

```
test <- function(year){
    years = paste(year, collapse = ",")

    print(paste('and year in (', years,')'))
}
```

And results:

```
test(1)
# "and year in ( 1 )"

test(c(1, 2, 3))
# "and year in ( 1,2,3 )"
```

Comment: But with `paste` you can specify which character is used to collapse the vector elements. For example, the requested format did not include spaces between elements. I know this is subtle, and perhaps irrelevant in this case...

Comment: @RichardScriven yes, you're right, I've rephrased my answer accordingly.