# Reduce() and ... (ellipsis)

Tags: r, functional-programming, ellipsis

Following [Hadley's advice in *Advanced R*](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals-fp), I'm trying to create a recursive version of a merger function using `Reduce()`. However, his example uses a vector of numbers, e.g.

```
Reduce(`+`, 1:3)
[1] 6
```

Whereas I want to be able to give multiple argument using ... (ellipsis). What I have in mind is something like this:

```
merge_datasets_multi = function(..., main=1, time=F) {
  #wrap with Reduce
  Reduce(function(x, y) merge_datasets(x, y, main=main, time=time), ...)

  #debugging, verify that the anonymous function works
  #(function(x, y) merge_datasets(x, y, main=main, time=time))(iris[1:50, ], iris[51:100, ])
}
```

The `merge_datasets()` function is in [my personal package](https://github.com/Deleetdk/kirkegaard).

I have tested that the anonymous function I make works when given two arguments.

However, this throws an error:

```
merge_datasets_multi(iris[1:50, ], iris[51:100, ], iris[101:150, ])
Error in if (right) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (right) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Called from: Reduce(function(x, y) merge_datasets(x, y, main = main, time = time), 
    ...)
```

Presumably this is because the third argument (a `data.frame`) gets passed to a conditional, which fails to evaluate to true or false and throws the error.

Thus, if we instead give it a `list` of `data.frames`, it should work:

```
merge_datasets_multi(list(iris[1:50, ], iris[51:100, ], iris[101:150, ]))
```

And it does. However, this requires the extra step for the user of adding the data.frames into a `list` before calling `merge_datasets_multi()`.

I tried passing `as.list(...)` as the argument to `Reduce()`, but it doesn't work. The output is just the first `data.frame` converted to a `list`.

How does one make a sequential function with `Reduce()` that takes `...` as input?

Comment: `Reduce`-functions need to be designed as having two arguments (x & y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is apparently simple. Instead of trying `as.list()`, one should just use `list()`. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057419/3980197).

```
library(magrittr)
merge_datasets_multi = function(..., main=1, time=F) {
  #wrap with Reduce
  Reduce(function(x, y) merge_datasets(x, y, main=main, time=time), list(...))
}
merge_datasets_multi(iris[1:50, ], iris[51:100, ], iris[101:150, ]) %>% dim
[1] 150   5
```