# Unexpected behavior from `...` in a function's definition

Tags: r, wrapper

**NB:** This question is *not* a duplicate of [How to use R's ellipsis feature when writing your own function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341).  That question asks how to use ellipses, and in particular, "how can [one] convert the ellipsis from the function's signature into, for example, a list?"  Below I don't ask anything of the sort.  I am asking why my use of ellipses fails to produce the expected result.

---

As an example, the function `my.ls` below is meant to be a wrapper around `base::ls` that makes `all.names = TRUE` the default:

```
my.ls <- function (...) base::ls(..., all.names = TRUE)
```

I had expected that, with this definition, `my.ls()` would produce the same value as `base::ls(all.names = TRUE)` does.  To my surprise, the values from these two expressions are not even close.

For example:

```
% /usr/bin/R --quiet --vanilla
> x <- 3; .y <- 1; z <- 4
> base::ls(all.names = TRUE)
[1] "x"  ".y" "z" 
> my.ls <- function (...) base::ls(..., all.names = TRUE)
> my.ls()
[1] "..."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out the problem.  The following implementation of `my.ls` is closer to what I'm after:

```
my.ls <- function (name, all.names = TRUE, ...) {
    if (missing(name))
        return(my.ls(parent.frame(1), all.names = all.names, ...))

    base::ls(name, all.names = all.names, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it because the default argument for `envir` in `base::ls` is `as.environement(pos)`?

Adding `envir = gloal.env()` seems to work for me, assuming you are working from the global environment.