# How to get questions' text using the stackr library for the API?

Tags: r, stackexchange-api

Using [stackr](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr) it is possible, with the following command, to list the questions from a specific user.

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/stackr")
library(stackr)
textques <- stack_users(712603, "questions", num_pages=10, pagesize=100)
```

Is it possible to have also the text of every question?

[There is](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) a body option but how could I use it with the previous command?

Also, I tried body equals true but it is not working:

```
textques <- stack_users(712603, "questions", body = "true", num_pages=10, pagesize=100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [`stack_users()`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr/blob/master/R/stack_users.R#L16) and [`stack_GET()`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr/blob/master/R/api.R#L62) function both accept (and pass on) the [ellipsis argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057341/1255289), you can add any parameter onto the end of the API call URL. This includes the `filter` parameter, where we can use [the built-in `withbody` filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters):

```
library(stackr)
questions <- stack_users(9371451, "questions", num_pages=10, pagesize=100, filter="withbody")
for (i in 1:nrow(questions)) {
    qtext <- questions$body[i]
    print(qtext)
}
```

Output:

```
[1] "<p>I would like to use the Stack Exchange API with a specific user id to get the text of a user's badges.</p>\n\n<p>I found <a href=\"https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr\" rel=\"nofollow noreferrer\">the <em>stackr</em> library for the Stack Exchange API</a>, and tried this:</p>\n\n<pre><code># install.packages(\"devtools\")\nlibrary(devtools)\ndevtools::install_github(\"dgrtwo/stackr\")\nlibrary(stackr)\nstack_users(712603)\n</code></pre>\n\n<p>But that only gives the total number of every kind of badge. How can I take the text from each one?\nExample:</p>\n\n<pre><code>gold silver bronze\nr     r      ggplot2\n</code></pre>\n\n<p>I don't only want the total number of badges but also what the badges are.</p>\n"
[1] "<p>Using stackr it is possible with the following command to take the question from a specific user.</p>\n\n<pre><code>library(devtools)\ndevtools::install_github(\"dgrtwo/stackr\")\nlibrary(stackr)\ntextques &lt;- stack_users(712603, \"questions\", num_pages=10, pagesize=100)\n</code></pre>\n\n<p>How is it possible to have also the text of every question?</p>\n\n<p><a href=\"https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question\">There is</a> a body option but how could I use it with the previous command</p>\n\n<p>Also I tried body equals true but it is not working:</p>\n\n<pre><code>textques &lt;- stack_users(712603, \"questions\", body = \"true\", num_pages=10, pagesize=100)\n</code></pre>\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the package provides a function to extract the question asked, but here's an approach based on `rvest`

```
for(i in 1:nrow(textques)){
  link <- textques$link[i]
  textques$qtext[i] <- read_html(link) %>% html_node("#question .post-text") %>% html_text()
}
```

This should add another variable to your existing dataframe with the text of the question in each link.

Comment: Thank you it is a nice solution but please let me search a little more if is possible to make it through api because as I can understand rvest is making directly calls and let's say it makes more traffic to site and if I use it for a list of many users there is a possibility to receive an error.