# R: How do I call elements from my elipsis variables inside a loop in a function?

Tags: r, function, variables

I use elipsis because I want to use a varying number of variables in my function. I cannot seem to call the individual elements in a loop and use them in simple mathematical operations.

```
tst <- function(...) {
  print(..1)
  q = 1 + ..1
  print(q)
  for (i in 1:3) {
    val <- get(paste0("..", i))
    print(val)
    s = 1 + val  
  }
}
```

If I run `tst(1, 3, 4)` I expect to get output like

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 4
```

Instead I get

> [1] 1
>
> Error in get(paste0("..", i)) : object '..1' not found

This tells me that outside the loop, the `..1` is recognized as a numeric object, and yet inside the loop it cannot find it.

Comment: I apologize for the formatting. I am trying to fix it, but....

Comment: use `for (i in c(...))`

Comment: I like Shane's answer for simplicity (use `args = list(...)`, then you can loop, `lapply`, `do.call`, etc.), but there's lots of info at (possible duplicate) [How to use R's ellipsis feature when writing your own function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057419/903061)

Comment: Because I am using this in mle it turns out I cannot use "...". As a result I need to be able to use a loop an call the arguments in the function, but I cannot get the call recognized as a variable. I would like the call of tst(1,2,3) to be
[1] 2  and [1] 2. Instead it is 
[1] 2
[1] "p2"       where                                                                                                tst <- function(p1,p2,p3) {
  print(p2)
  print(paste0("p","2"))}.   Should I be posting this as a separate question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set a vector to equal the arguments at the outset, then you can refer to them by an index. Everywhere you used `...` I replaced with the indexing vector `val[[]]`:

```
tst <- function(...) {
  val <- c(...)
  print(val[[1]])
  q = 1 + val[[1]]
  print(q)
  for (i in 1:3) {
    print(val[[i]])
    s = 1 + val[[i]]  
  }
}
```

Output:

```
> tst(1, 3, 4)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 4
```

Comment: Thank you everyone!