# Why is argument not passed by apply()?

Tags: r

After really annoying and long debugging, I found that `apply()` does not pass arguments to functions via `...`! Here is a simplified example (this is a simplified example to demonstrate the error):

```
A <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
apply(A, 1, function (x, ...) { cat("argument arg1: "); print(arg1); }, arg1 = 10)
# Argument arg1: Error in print(arg1) (from #1) : object 'arg1' not found
```

Do you have any idea why or what to do with this? Workaround is obvious, to list all arguments instead of using ..., which is anoying since I use this as a wrapper for other more complex functions. Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057341/680068

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't that that argument is not being passed to the function (it is), the problem is you are not "catching" it via a named parameter. This works for example

```
apply(A, 1, function (x, ..., arg1) { cat("argument arg1: "); print(arg1); }, arg1 = 10)
```

And we can use that variable as `arg1` in the function because we caught it. Otherwise it's left inside the `...` so you can pass it along to another function. For example we can just pass everything to list like this...

```
apply(A, 1, function (x, ...) { print(list(...)) }, arg1 = 10)
```

So since your function uses `...` those values that aren't named stay "in" the dots. In order to get them out you need to capture them as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass more than one argument, you may use mappy() instead.

`mapply(your_function, arg1, arg2, argn`

Comment: Only if you need to iterate over all those arguments in parallel, which it doesn't seem like OP wants.