# What is the variable "...." in functions?

Tags: r

I sometimes meet the following code

```
foo <- function(x,y,...){

}
```

What is "..." ?

Is there any reference?

Comment: See section 10.4 of "An Introduction to R". (`help.start()`)

Comment: it's varargs, if you're familiar with other languages

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function

Comment: There's the `?"..."` help page (also called `?dots`) for the official reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...` is used to pass optional additional arguments to a function. Here is one example :

```
foo <- function(x, y, ...) paste(x, y, ...)

foo('a', 'bcd')
#[1] "a bcd"

foo('a', 'bcd', 'aaa')
#[1] "a bcd aaa"

foo('a', 'bcd', 'aaa', 'def')
#[1] "a bcd aaa def"
```

The documentation of this is present at `?"..."`.