# Why are ylim and xlim not working in pairs plot?

Tags: r, plot

I've been trying to adjust the axes of multiple plots using `pairs`, such that they are all on the same axis. Here's a reproducible example:

```
structure(list(LS_avg_RT_diff_L1 = c(80.6931818181818, 132.140625, 
17.3957219251338, 17.7260619977038, 132.270508203281, 48.7419786096257, 
61.5816849816849, 44.4324596774193, 80.8417471466198, 65.4357864357864, 
83.2645687645688, 36.264116575592, 67.0728778467909, 60.1642857142856, 
-14.4822346891071, 45.9939516129032, 42.7380090497737, 90.2058823529412, 
27.6024667931689, 93.5517494494738), LS_avg_RT_diff_L2 = c(77.5145135566187, 
40.8939393939395, 29.6952853598016, 72.9280753968254, -14.1512868801005, 
85.6644052464948, 30.2159709618876, -11.433465085639, 64.1141025641025, 
74.4760374050264, 53.6344431687714, 43.5934426229509, -9.48846153846159, 
36.4078947368421, 22.3389830508474, 37.0996168582376, 3.98615617564349, 
101.859614968635, 15.8340548340548, 64.2138275124732), F_Avg_RT_incong_cong_diff = c(171.598614692351, 
102.555176953458, 137.872214816226, 125.230948166877, 51.7965631337389, 
134.295988295988, 120.740762463343, 100.648528099911, 106.099431818182, 
105.072854715378, 70.708551526529, 123.551755014327, 96.0822281167109, 
122.687703999003, 119.429894937918, 120.140225128698, 76.5200041540099, 
111.617893755825, 213.413735177866, 143.796112730807), CS_Avg_RT_sw_stay_diff = c(96.0248439450687, 
13.6687620889749, 43.9708908113163, 106.518604651163, 77.4642017245884, 
31.8150793650793, -54.9493941553814, 43.6563866241286, 11.0111111111111, 
18.3352925809822, 30.7129426129426, 21.9990338164251, -27.7946428571429, 
28.8394863563403, 6.10227272727275, 20.1549806576402, 79.845259391771, 
12.6738336713995, 4.97893772893769, 54.8049335863378)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And my code:

```
panel <- function(x,y){
        points(x,y, col = "blue", pch = 21, bg = "blue")
        abline(lm(y~x), col="red")}

my.text.panel <- function(labels) {
  function(x, y, lbl, ...) {
    if (lbl %in% names(labels)) lbl <- labels[[lbl]]
    text(x, y, lbl, ...)}}

pairs(x = Corr_data_noppt[1:4], 
      xlim = c(-100, 250),
      ylim = c(-100, 250),
      diag.panel = labels,
      text.panel = my.text.panel(c(LS_avg_RT_diff_L1="RT Switching costs for L1", 
                                   LS_avg_RT_diff_L2="RT Switching costs for L2",
                                   F_Avg_RT_incong_cong_diff="Flanker RT costs", 
                                   CS_Avg_RT_sw_stay_diff="Colour-Shape RT costs")),
      lower.panel = panel,
      font.labels = 1, 
      cex.labels = 1.2,
      upper.panel = NULL) #show only the low half of the matrix
```

According to other cases on here, `xlim` and `ylim` can be added as arguments to `pairs`, but that doesn't work for me and I get an error that they are not taken as such:

```
Error in upper.panel(...) : 
  unused arguments (xlim = c(-100, 250), ylim = c(-100, 250))
```

I tried alternatively adding them onto:

```
panel <- function(x,y){
        points(x,y, col = "blue", pch = 21, bg = "blue")
        abline(lm(y~x), col="red")
        xlim = c(-100, 250)
        ylim = c(-100, 250)}
```

But that changed absolutely nothing.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `Corr_data_noppt`?

Comment: It's just the name of my data frame.

Comment: Interesting. the cause is the combination of lower.panel = panel and the xlim argument. I am not sure if you can get around it, but whenever i commented one of them, it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow additional arguments (e. g. `xlim`) to your custom panel function by [using the dot-dot-dot (`...`) construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function):

```
panel <- function(x, y, ...){
        points(x,y, col = "blue", pch = 21, bg = "blue")
        abline(lm(y~x), col="red")}
```

Comment: Or define xlim / ylim: in your function: `panel <- function(x, y){
        plot(x, y, col = "blue", pch = 21, bg = "blue", xlim = c(-100, 250), ylim = c(-100, 250))
        abline(lm(y~x), col="red")
}`