# Output error/warning log (txt file) when running R script under command line

Tags: r, command-line, error-handling

If I run R script under command line (actually I run that from calling in VBA), how can I output any error/warning messages to a txt file?

Comment: How about yourprogram.exe > anoutputfile.txt ? Although that captures everything. On *nix you could direct stderr, not sure about Win*. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109017/how-do-you-print-to-stderr-in-r

Comment: You can possibly use `sink()`

Comment: Thank you. I tried to search in web on how to use sink in R but a bit confused on how to output error/warning message in my case. Would you mind give me a quick example on how to do that? Thank you again.

Comment: I roughly know how sink() works, but I can only output variables to the output txt file, how to output error message?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `sink()` to divert messages as well as warnings to a file.  The trick is to set the argument `type="message"`:

Here is an example adapted from the help for `?sink`:

```
setwd(tempdir())

## capture messages and errors to a file.
zz <- file("all.Rout", open="wt")
sink(zz, type="message")

try(log("a"))

## reset message sink and close the file connection
sink(type="message")
close(zz)

## Display the log file
readLines("all.Rout")
[1] "Error in log(\"a\") : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function"
```

Comment: However, how can I close the connection with the log file? I tried sink(), but when I want to delete the log file, I cannot delete that, as seems there is still connection. Only after I closed my R, I can delete that. How should I close the connection?

Comment: This is because in the original answer, sink was not terminated with `type="message"` and the connection was not closed.  (Fixed in the updated answer)

Answer (score 21):

To close the connection with the log file you have to use `sink(type="message")` instead of `sink()` and then `close(zz)`.