# How to write (or access?) log of errors and warnings in R

Tags: r, logging, error-handling, warnings

Can anyone tell me how to keep a simple log of errors and warnings thrown during sourcing of code in R?  Specifically I want to write them to an object during sourcing so I can print them into a message after execution in case the user missed it as the lines scrolled by.

Background:  I wrote a small data validation program, about 600 lines, that allows the user to select an excel file which will be automatically imported, processed, and exported again.  I tried hard to include automatic checks in the code (such as checking for required column names and throwing a pop up box if not present), but am aware that I can't think of every possible error that could occur, especially with other users.  What I would like is to have every error/warning/etc. that occurs during sourcing to be written to an object that I could then call later such as in a pop up box.  I have been able to figure out every step except for creating the error log.

```
ErrorLog <- (code for collecting errors/warnings here)

(Program Code - already completed)

ErrorPopUp <- tkmessageBox(title = "ERRORS", message = paste("
Please note the following errors/warnings occurred during file processing:

", 
ErrorLog , 

"To proceed and export file please press OK.  To exit the program without      
saving, please press cancel."), icon = "warning", type = "okcancel")

(code to continue and export or quit)
```

I appreciate any ideas, and thx for the patience as I saw many posts on advanced topics such as creating your own error messages or sending them to windows, but none for simply writing an object listing them.

Comment: `tryCatch`ing the errors, `cat`ing them to a file, or [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666086/output-error-warning-log-txt-file-when-running-r-script-under-command-line)

Comment: Don't have a full solution bu running R CMD BATCH file.R saves the output to a log file. Alternatively you can use knitr::spin and possible only keep error messages.

Comment: hmmm...  I know I don't want an external file, just an object in the global environment that clears when the program closes.  I always know just enough to get get myself stuck on another problem O.o haha.  I will have to learn more about     tryCatch and     cat but they look intriguing if I can figure them out.  Thank you for the suggestion @rawr

Comment: I have knitr installed, I will have to learn to use it better it sounds like.  I love programming but have a long way to go I think.   Thank you @timcdlucas for the suggestions.

Comment: @rawr suggestion of sink and tryCatch has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: Can one of you write basic instructions on how to do this with tryCatch and cat?  I will be sure to mark it as the correct answer if it works, but I have no idea how to get started doing this on my own.