# R: Sink(type="message") for error reporting - can I get a line number?

Tags: r, error-handling, error-reporting, line-numbers, sink

TL;DR: I'm using sink() to log errors during a script run, and saving them to a dataframe that can be viewed post-run, to highlight errors. I'd like a way to include the error line number, if possible.

'

Long version: I'm writing an R script to process national weather datasets, which sometimes contain anomalies - missing data, unexpected symbols, etc. It's possible that inconsistencies in the data could cause errors in the script, which is fine for me as the programmer - I can identify and fix them. However, my eventual goal is to make it broadly applicable to any national weather dataset - this means it might be used by people with little R knowledge. The script is presently ~700 lines long and will be getting quite a bit longer, with a number of user-defined functions. This makes reviewing the console history rather tedious, especially for novice R users.

My solution so far has been to save all error and warning messages generated during a script run to a table, which would be the first thing the user sees after a run, forcing them to acknowledge errors. I'm using the sink() function (I found the method on another SO post, attributed in the code comments below), and it works beautifully, EXCEPT that I can't figure out a way to log the line number for error messages. Traceback() won't work in this context, as I want all errors, not just the most recent one in the stack.

As written, my code is below. I mainly work in RStudio, so I run this by pasting the block into the console.

```
 # Method accesed online Nov 24, 2016, at:
 # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666086/output-error-warning-log-txt-file-when-running-r-script-under-command-line
 setwd(tempdir()) # tempdir() creates names for temporary files

 # Capture messages and errors to a file
 zz=file("all.Rout",open="wt") # file() creates a file connection and opens it 
                               #  in wt="write text mode".
 sink(zz,type="message") # sink diverts R output to a connection - in this case, the error log, zz

 # test out some error samples (4)
 try(log("a")) # try runs an expression and allows user code to handle error-recovery
 z x a # try() is not necessary - any error will be flagged and entered to the log
 mean()
 sds(42)

 # Display log file
 readLines("all.Rout")
 error.log=data.frame(readLines("all.Rout")) # write these to an error log DF

 # Reset sink, close connection
 sink(type="message") # this prevents diversion of messages -
                      # they will now appear in console, as default
 close(zz) # close the error log connection
 remove(zz) # blank from mem

 # OK, this is good - but can I get line numbers to output to the DF?
```

Can anyone recommend a way to make this work with sink()?

Alternatively, if you know of some other way to get to my desired output (a list/table of error/warning messages and their locations in the code), I'm all ears.

Comment: I don't think this would illustrate capturing "line numbers"  since there really are no line numbers during console input. The line numbers I am aware of are constructed during script parsing. See `?parse`. The `?traceback` page also suggests considering setting `options(error = function() traceback(2))`

Comment: Thanks - I guess there's no way to retroactively identify an error's location in interactive mode, then? Setting my error option to traceback(2) prints the stack at the time of the error's occurrence, but this print isn't captured by sink(), so it's basically the same problem - the errors are highlighted at the time in interactive mode, now with the call stack rather than an error message. No new information is yielded into sink().

I'll have to learn more about source(). Seems like this is the only way to run the code and have line numbers returned, as in your comment on parse().

Comment: to work around sink, why don't you comment out all sink commands and the equivalent of main, enter an R session/shell, source the file and then run it? That way, you can set options and use traceback

Comment: @MikePalmice - You've hit on the main problem here; this approach to error reporting doesn't work when running code interactively. For something like this, I should be sourcing the script anyway, in which case error tracebacks work.