# R command line best practices: exit, print stdout, print stderr, avoid warnings

Tags: r

Currently I run R scripts the following way:

```
R --slave < <script_fullname> argument1 argument2 ...
```

I was wondering the best practices in R on how to exit the script with a warning, would q() just do it?

```
if(!file.exists(argument1)){
q()
```

}

print to the stdout

```
    if(!file.exists(argument1)){
    print('file does not exist')
    q()
}
```

and print to the std err?

Also, I see the following warning everytime I run R scripts this way.  When reading the stdout I see:

```
ARGUMENT 'argument1' __ignored__
ARGUMENT 'argument2' __ignored__
```

Is there anyway to avoid such warnings?

Comment: You forgot the closing ')' for your if statements

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to exit your R script because of an error, I suggest using
 `stop("warning message here")` rather than `print()` and `q()`.

`print()` is not recommended, since "it’s hard to capture and selectively ignore this sort of output. Printed output is not a condition, so you can’t use any of the useful condition handling tools." -- from [Debugging, condition handling, and defensive programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html)

stderr is discussed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109017/how-do-you-print-to-stderr-in-r) (too long to repeat all of the options here).

Try using `--args` to avoid the warnings:
`R --slave < <script_fullname> --args argument1 argument2 ...`

See also [Passing Custom Arguments](https://projects.uabgrid.uab.edu/r-group/wiki/CommandLineProcessing#PassingCustomArguments).