# Return only one value from RScript when sourced from shell

Tags: r

Im running an rscript from `bash` script using:

```
retval=`./rcode.r`
```

In `rcode` `print` is called many times for debugging purpose. When retval is checked, it has values from all `print` statements.

How to return only a single value from a script? Is there any other command to use? What is the right way to return a value from r script to the caller(console/bash)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109017/how-do-you-print-to-stderr-in-r (you need to "print" diagnostics to `stderr` so your "single value" is the only thing on `stdout` and I think you want to use \`./rcode.r` or `$(./rcode.r)` vs the double-quoted thing you are using.

Comment: How does `retval="./rcode.r"` run anything in bash? Have some backticks gone missing because StackOverflow uses them to style code? Did you mean `retval="\`./rcode.r\`"` ?

Comment: Yes as SO uses ``  for styleing i used double quotues. I am using backticks for execution.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks. from the link i could see `write` can be used. also `message` seems better which by default redirects to `stderr`. A comprehensive answer is found in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699272/why-is-message-a-better-choice-than-print-in-r-for-writing-a-package