# Print output from R script in Bash

Tags: r, linux, bash

I have a .sh script with calls internally a R script.

This R Script use some directories that I print in my program.

My problem is that the output I am generating in my R script is used after its execution another time in the .sh script.

Example:

1. Calls **join_files.sh**, we pass init_month / end_month
2. Using this init and end month the R script joins all files between those months
3. I want to get that directories that are being used by my R script, I print them in the R Script and using 'cat' command in R I
       can get them, but all extra information is being printed.

Is there a way to print directly in the shell using R script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you print to stderr in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109017/how-do-you-print-to-stderr-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `suppressMessages` that you dont want and only print the needed info.
Example:

```
$ cat sample.sh
output=`Rscript sample.R`
echo $output

$ cat sample.R
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
i=100
print(i)

$ sh sample.sh
1 100
```